# How to handle a slot's onClick event in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to build a reusable Dialog without having to make use of any `refs` to interact with the dialog. It has 2 named slots. `activator` and `content`.

`activator` can be any element that when clicked will cause the dialog to open (some text, an icon, etc). `content` is the content to display in the dialog.

I think that I have created everything correctly however the on Click handler doesn't seem to work on the `activator` slot. The dialog does not show. See code below:

**PopupDialog.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <slot @click="dialog = true" name="activator" />
    </div>

    <v-dialog
      v-model="dialog"
      persistent
      max-width="400"
    >
      <slot name="content" />
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "PopupDialog",
  data: () => ({
    dialog: false,
  }),
};
</script>
```

And then I try using the component like this:

```
  <PopupDialog>
    <template v-slot:activator>
      <span>
        Add Member
      </span>
    </template>

    <template v-slot:content>
      <span>
        Content to show in dialog
      </span>
    </template>
  </PopupDialog>
```

When I click the span text nothing happens, why is that? Is it not possible to use event listeners on slots? How would I be able to make this work?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Nothing happens because you can't apply an event listener to slot children like that.

Instead, you could pass a method as a slot prop to the `activator` slot, so that children can bind a `click` event handler to that method:

```html
<slot name="activator" :onClick="onClick" />
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'PopupDialog',
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.dialog = true
    }
  }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```html
<PopupDialog>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ onClick }">
    <span @click="onClick"> Add Member </span>
  </template>
</PopupDialog>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-method-as-slot-prop-in-vue-k7pow?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Just wanted to say this was extremely helpful. Thanks!